# Action function rerender not working sometimes

Tags: visualforce, rerender, actionfunction

I have a outputpanel in visualforce page which has scripts opens up modal dialog. I call the action function on close of the dialog which rerender the outputpanel to get the value '{!shortListString}' from the controller. The problem is the rerender is not working sometime. Any ideas?

```
<apex:actionFunction name="setAlreadyShortListedCandidateMap" action="{!setAlreadyShortListedCandidateMap}" status="pgStatus" reRender="searchResultPanel,PageMessages,shortPanel,SA" oncomplete="Init();"/>


<apex:outputPanel id="shortPanel" >
        <script type="text/javascript">            

        // Method to check if the candidate is already shortlisted end
            function GetShortListCandidates()
            {
                $('.modal-content').css('width','auto');
                $( "#shortListContent" ).empty();
                var shortListed = '{!shortListString}';
                if(shortListed != '')
                {
                    var parsedShortlist = '';
                    parsedShortlist = JSON.parse(shortListed);                        
                    var map = new Object();
                    var htmlHeader = "<tr><th>Action</th><th style='min-width:100%;'>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>Last Interview Date</th><th>Last Interview Status</th><th>Last Interview Type</th><th>Last Interviewer</th></tr>";

                    var html = '';
                    for(var i in parsedShortlist)
                    { 
                       console.log(parsedShortlist[i]);
                       var contactId = parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__c;
                       //var shortListName = parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Name == null ? '' : parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Name;
                       var email = typeof(parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__r.Email) == 'undefined' ? '' : parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__r.Email;
                       var lastInterviewDate = parsedShortlist[i].lastInterviewDate == null ? '' : parsedShortlist[i].lastInterviewDate;
                       var lastInterviewers = parsedShortlist[i].lastInterviewers == null ? '' : parsedShortlist[i].lastInterviewers;
                       var lastInterviewStatus = parsedShortlist[i].lastInterviewStatus == null ? '' : parsedShortlist[i].lastInterviewStatus;
                       var lastInterviewType = parsedShortlist[i].lastInterviewType == null ? '' : parsedShortlist[i].lastInterviewType;
                       var phone = typeof(parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__r.Phone) == 'undefined' ? '' : parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__r.Phone;
                       //html += "<tr><td align='left'><a onclick=openSubtab('/"+parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__r.Id+"'); href='#'>" + parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__r.Name + "</a></td><td align='left'>" + shortListName + "</td><td align='left'>" + email +"</td><td align='left'>" + phone +"</td><td align='left'>" + lastInterviewDate +"</td><td align='left'>" + lastInterviewStatus +"</td><td align='left'>" + lastInterviewType +"</td><td align='left'>" + lastInterviewers +"</td></tr>";
                       html += "<tr><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='"+parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__r.FirstName + parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__r.LastName+"' onclick='removeShortlistJSPopup(this, \"" + contactId + "\")'>Remove</button></td><td align='left'><a onclick=openSubtab('/"+parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__r.Id+"'); href='#'>" + parsedShortlist[i].shortListRec.Candidate__r.Name + "</a></td><td align='left'>" + email +"</td><td align='left'>" + phone +"</td><td align='left'>" + lastInterviewDate +"</td><td align='left'>" + lastInterviewStatus +"</td><td align='left'>" + lastInterviewType +"</td><td align='left'>" + lastInterviewers +"</td></tr>";
                    }
                    html = htmlHeader + html;
                    $('#shortListContent').append(html);
                    $('#shortListDialog').modal("show");
                }
            }

      </script>
  </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: from where are you calling this action function

Comment: Another javascript function is triggered on click of the button in the model popup. In that javascript function the action function is called

Comment: did you fill all required field on page.

Comment: nothing required.. the popup just displays information.. I don't know why the rerender not rendering the outputpanel sometime..

Comment: Have you tried to add "apex:pageMessages" tag to your visualforce page? That would help to shed some lights on this problem